# IO.File.Delete doesn't delete, but not error

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have some code that allows a user to import certain excel spreadsheets into the DB.  Now, I save a copy of the file to the server so I can read it:

```
fupMYfile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(target, fupMYfile.FileName));
```

So all works well there till i try to delete the file when I am done with it.  I don't receive and error, and I have checked the code gets called, however, it will not delete the file and won't give an error.

```
System.IO.File.Delete(target + fupMYfile.FileName);
```

I did try making sure that IIS_IUSRS has full access to the folder, so I know that is not an issue.

Anybody have any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Is the delete code in a `try` block with an empty `catch`? Did you debug through and see that this line is hit?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using `Path.Combine` in the first instance and not in the second? Have you written `target + fupMYfile.FileName` to a log to make sure the value is correct? If the file doesn't exist, that method does not throw an exception.

Comment: have you checked the path is ok ? Have you checked that the file is created correctly ?

Comment: I agree with Oded that there _may_ be an error that you're suppressing, accidentally or otherwise.  You might also try running something like ProcMon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to monitor the file system and see what it says about the delete attempt.

Comment: @Oded: Its part of the finally

Comment: The File.Delete page says `If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.`. I'd double check the paths.

Comment: I removed the delete from the finally and is not completely outside any try or catch, and it still doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not using the same file name. You are saving it something like `c:\somefolder\somefile.xls`, then you try to delete it at `c:\somefoldersomefile.xls`.

Use `Path.Compbine` to put the folder namd and the file name together:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(System.IO.Path.Combine(target, fupMYfile.FileName));
```

Comment: You're making an assumption. It's probably correct, but remember that `target` could have a trailing `\\`, or `fupMYfile.FileName` could have a leading `\\`.

Comment: Yeah, it was an assumption, but a good one.  We have a winner, winner, chicken dinner!  Adding the Combine resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`File.Delete` doesn't give any exception and hence will not throw an error, and we need to give full absolute path

```
File.Delete("C:\temp\tmpFile.txt");
```

and not

```
File.Delete("tmpFile.txt");
```